# In Drupal, is there a way to index files (pdf, doc) that were submitted via a Webform?

Tags: file, drupal, search, indexing, drupal-modules

I'm trying to figure out a solution on how to be able to index/search PDF, doc, and maybe txt files that were uploaded via a webform. I've found a module (Search API attachments) that will index files but it appears that it only indexes files that are attached to nodes. :(

Our client wants to be able to search the contents of resumés that are submitted from a webform.

Comment: What version of Drupal is this for?

Answer (score 0):

If your clients are expecting hundreds of nodes, it might be worthwhile to set up an Apache Solr. Then you can use Tika to index all kinds of files: http://tika.apache.org/

If that's not an option, you can write a custom module that uses the Webform API that saves the attached file as a node... and then use your Search API attachments module.

Comment: Search API Attachments actually uses Tika. The "file index" appears to index all files in the managed files table. (The trouble I'm having with it is the file index doesn't care if the node is published or not, so if you upload a document to a node before it's published, it shows up in the file index.)